# Why is this database trigger being executed twice by one commit?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I have developed a data processing engine in MarkLogic to handle data being exported into another VPC (virtual private cloud). I am not going to get into why we need this particular solution, I am aware of MLCP, etc. The data has to go through an ETL and schema validation process before offloading to a third party service to handle everything else.

Here is the basic design of the engine:

1. A document in the `exportable` collection (in the `content database`) is created or modified
2. One of two triggers will be fired, depending on whether the document is created or modified

   - Each trigger executes the same module `exportDataTrigger.sjs`
   - Create trigger `event` details:

     - `"collection-scope": { "uri": "exportable" }`
     - `"document-content": { "update-kind": "create" }`
     - `"when": "post-commit"`
   - Modify trigger `event` details:

     - `"collection-scope": { "uri": "exportable" }`
     - `"document-content": { "update-kind": "modify" }`
     - `"when": "post-commit"`
3. A copy of the document is added to `export database` with the `export` collection by the `exportDataTrigger.sjs` module
4. A trigger is fired when a document is created with the `export` collection

   - The trigger executes the `processExportData.sjs` module
   - Create trigger event details:

     - `"collection-scope": { "uri": "export" }`
     - `"document-content": { "update-kind": "create" }`
     - `"when": "post-commit"`
5. The `processExportData.sjs` module performs the following operations on the document:

   - Performs some ETL on the document content
   - Replaces the `export` collection with `processed` collection
   - Inserts the modified document via `xdmp.documentInsert`

     - Example: `xdmp.documentInsert(uri, processedDocument, xdmp.documentGetPermissions(uri), 'processed');`
6. A trigger is fired when a document is modified with the `processed` collection:

   - The trigger executes the `validateData.sjs` module
   - Modify trigger event details:

     - `"collection-scope": { "uri": "processed" }`
     - `"document-content": { "update-kind": "modify" }`
     - `"when": "post-commit"`
7. The `validateData.sjs` module performs the following operations on the document:

   - Data is compared against a JSON schema:

     - When data is valid:

       - An existing property `validated` is set to `true`
       - Replaces the `processed` collection with `export-ready` collection
       - Inserts the modified document via `xdmp.documentInsert`

         - Example: `xdmp.documentInsert(uri, processedDocument, xdmp.documentGetPermissions(uri), 'export-ready');`
     - When data does not match the schema:

       - An existing property `validated` is `false` by default
       - Replaces the `processed` collection with `needs-review` collection
       - Inserts the modified document via `xdmp.documentInsert`

         - Example: `xdmp.documentInsert(uri, processedDocument, xdmp.documentGetPermissions(uri), 'needs-review');`

Everything works fine until the trigger on step #6. It gets executed twice, even though the document is only updated once. I added a lot of logs throughout the code to check each transaction. I also checked to make sure I didn't actually add the trigger twice. I currently have my q-console set up to skip straight to step #3.

What would cause a trigger to fire twice on one update?

**Edit:**

I decided to comment out the code logic in the `validateData.sjs` module and just left the logs. It turns out it is triggering itself, an extra time. I still don't understand why, since I am committing the document once, with a new the trigger should not be fired on (either `export-ready` or `needs-review`)

Comment: I'd still like to know why this is happening, but I was able to work around it by disabling the trigger before the document is updated, then enabling it again after the update. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-commit triggers are spawned and executed as separate transaction from the one that updated the document.

You didn't show how the triggers were created or what options were set. Was the `recursive` parameter set to `false`?

https://docs.marklogic.com/trgr.createTrigger

> `recursive`    Set to `true` if the trigger should be allowed to trigger itself for recursive changes on the same document. Set to `false` to prevent the trigger from triggering itself. **If this parameter is not present, then its value is `true`.**

If not, then changes made to the document could trigger the modified trigger.

[Avoiding Infinite Trigger Loops (Trigger Storms)](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers#id_83795)

> ...you can avoid trigger storms by setting the `$recursive` parameter in the [`trgr.createTrigger()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/trgr.createTrigger) function to `fn:false()`.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer. It seems logical. Typically we create triggers via JSON configs. I did include the "event" details used to create each trigger. I excluded all the irrelevant properties ("name", "module", etc.) I should have included the "recursive" property in my question details. I don't have the code any more, since I moved to a different approach, but I will leave it up incase someone else runs into this issue. I am 90% sure we would have had the recursive property set to false. I looked at the other triggers and they all have it set to false in the configs.

Comment: At the time, I did check the logs for trigger storms and did not find any. I think I may have deployed the same trigger under different names.